# What should be design approach - ListView Vs LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have an activity which shows these three things in order.

1. ViewFlipper (User can fling it left/right)
2. EditText
3. ListView  (List view can have n number of rows. lets limit it for 100. each row has images which get downloaded asynchronously)

I want that user can scroll vertically so I put above three item in single relative layout and that in to scrollView

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>  
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem with this approach

ListView and scroll view together is bad user-experience. When List will cover all screen user will have problem in scrolling complete view itself.

Solution which I could think of

1. Disable Scroll on ListView and let it show all items (Is this good enough)
2. User addHeaderView (not sure how to use it)

Second Approach (Which I did and ran into problems).

Instead of using ListView add LinearLayout (replacement of listrow) dynamically.

Problem with this approach

Lot of ugly coding as there is no sophisticated adapter for such scenarios. Need to populate each LinearLayout and it creates more issue because I have async Image loading for every LinearLayout.

What could be better approach. Any alternates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView vs LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483809/listview-vs-linearlayout)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `ScrollView` and a `ListView` together, this is a bad thing as mentioned by *Romain Guy*, the creator of `ListView`. The problem with you `LinearLayout` approach is performance: you will need to create *n* new `Views`, while the `ListView` just reuses existing ones.

The solution I could think of (in case it is not possible to make your Layout components to fit on the screen without scrolling), you could disable scrolling in your ListView and add "scroll up" and "scroll down" buttons, setting the `onClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` to let the user control scrolling speed. Though this might be not the best approach. Consider re-disigning your layout so the components fit on a single screen. This is usually not a good user expierince to enable scrolling because of layout components not fitting on a single screen. Your could add a page more to your `ViewFlipper` and place your `ListView` there for example

Comment: By design, my ViewFlipper covers half of the scree and then there is a TextVew so there is very less space to show ListView. It actually shows first item of ListView to give a hint to scroll down. And I  "Scroll Up" and "Scroll Down" are little counter intuitive.

Comment: well, the ListView CAN scroll, so you are able to define fixed positions for all elements without needing a ScrollView. A good user expirience is to provide multiple layouts for different screen sizes, so just make sure that all elements fit on the screen in any layout type